# Reconnecting call with WebRtc after network offline Android

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I try to reconnect after network offline.
I success to re connecting to call if the network fail in receiver side.
But i don't success to do it if network fail in the caller side.

I try to re -init the web WebRTC client , it's don't work.
Also try to create new offer , it's also don't work.

Do anyone know how to handle re connect in android with WebRTC?

Comment: have you solved this issue

Comment: if i am trying to reconnect by creating offer, its getting crashed.. can you please share the solution

Comment: @KumarKalluri it's was some times ago.. what i remember is that you need to do all process from start.. create offer with same id and node dont work..

Answer (score 0):

My case was slightly different since I ran into this issue while trying to implement WIFI > DATA network connection transition but I'm confident that this should work for you as well.

The solution for me was to recreate the offer and add a new constraint `IceRestart` in `MediaConstraints` and set it to `true`:

```
val mediaConstraint = MediaConstraints().apply {
    mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart", "true"))
}
```

Then you just add the param in `createOffer()` (which you should probably have already) like so:

```
peerConnection.createOffer(object : SdpObserver() {
    override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
        // normal implementation
    }
},mediaConstraint)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just want to clarify, when you first establish the connection the Offer will not contain the above constraint? only upon experiencing disconnection while generating a new Offer?